# Sorting and reinserting elements removes bound functions

Tags: jquery

I need to sort some rows after they've been inserted.  What I'm doing now is:

```
var $r = $tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a,b) { 
  return compare(taxstatusOf(a), taxstatusOf(b));
});
$tbody.empty().append($r);
```

This works, *except* that functions that were bound to elements contained in the rows are no longer bound (or no longer fire, which amounts to the same thing).

So, is there a right way to sort rows that doing fail like this?  Do I have to re-bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh.

The right answer, sports fans, is `.detach()`.  `.remove()` is supposed to strip the removed elements bare (removing local data and bound functions and such), which is great for garbage-collection and so forth but exactly what you don't want when you're planning to re-attach them later.

The working code:

```
var $r = $tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a,b) { 
  return compare(taxstatusOf(a), taxstatusOf(b));
}).detach().appendTo($tbody);
```

(I'm not going to "accept" my own answer for a little while in case someone comes up with a better one.)

(I guess it's *good* that I found the answer 30 seconds after posting the question.  Now the next guy on SO will profit from my mistake.)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `detach()`. While I think my answer is correct, so far as it goes, I do prefer your solution. Hence the +1, obviously.

Comment: @DavidThomas -- yeah, `.live()` and `.delegate()` make me very, very nervous.  They remind me of all those Sci-Fi stories where someone builds a machine to perform some useful function and to *keep doing it*.  And centuries later...

Answer (score 0):

From the sample code you provide it looks like you're removing the original elements from the DOM and then re-adding them. As the newly-sorted elements weren't present in the DOM when the events were originally bound they have no events/functions bound to them.

To work around this, you could assign the original functions/events using `live()` or `delegate()`, which will bind to 'future,' as well as 'current,' elements; or you would indeed have to 're-bind' the events in your sorting code, obviously after the line `$tbody.empty().append($r);`.